# Async loop inside promise - how to keep order

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch, async.js

Before rendering page I need to make sure that all stuff fetched from api call is saved to database.

```
     let saveUsersToDB = function () {
        //fetch users func
        return getAllUsers.then((data) => {
            //save to db func
            async.each(data, (user, callback) => {
                //Mongoose model
                let newUser = new User;
                //save to db
                newUser.save((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err)
                    }
                    else {
                        callback('user saved');
                    }
                })
               // async.each callback
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('error');
                } else {
                    console.log('Async each done');
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

When I call this like:

```
saveUsersToDB().then(()=>{
    console.log("All users saves")
})
```

The result is:

```
  //All users saved
  //Async each done
```

I can't figure out proper construction to keep right order in then() chain.

Comment: Not familiar with the `async` methods, but I suppose you would need to create a new Promise, resolve (or reject) it in the callback, and return the promise. Or use `Promise.all` instead, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

The callback for getAllUsers.then should return a promise. Otherwise the saveUsersToDB.then callback will be invoked immediately following getAllUsers.

```
//fetch users func
let saveUsersToDB = () => getAllUsers.then( ( data ) => new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

    //save to db func
    async.each( data, ( user, callback ) => {

        //Mongoose model
        let newUser = new User();

        //save to db
        newUser.save( ( err ) => {

            if ( err ) return callback( err );
            console.log( "user saved" );
            callback();

       } );

   // async.each callback

    }, function ( err ) {

        if ( err ) return reject( err );
        console.log( "all users saved" );
        resolve();

    } );

} ) );

saveUsersToDB().then( () => console.log( "done" ) );
```

Comment: to add to this, as he is already using promises and mongoose supports them as well, he should make use of promise.all + data.map or data.reduce instead of async.each

Comment: resolve() is what I was looking for. This solution works for me, thanks a lot @vox!